# "Contemptuous bastard", doesn't it sound rude?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

I've come across ['the grim reaper is  gone'](http://www.consented.co.uk/read/iain-duncan-smith-resigns-the-grim-reaper-is-gone/) and been surprised to encounter that they have put **contemptuous bastard** in the article:

> "This contemptuous bastard of a man has overseen “welfare reforms” that would have made Thatcher blush – from the changing of the Disability Living Allowance to “Personal Independence Payments”, repeated attacks on Employment and Support Allowance, and the utterly disgusting abolishment of the Independent Living Fund."

What does **contemptuous bastard** actually mean in that context?

Comment: It is rude. It is a derogatory remark.

Comment: It actually means *contemptuous bastard*. It is not necessarily rude if the description fits; I guess it depends on one's opinion of the issues or Iain Duncan-Smith. It is certainly strong language.

Comment: ..  and there's stronger to come in this article- including the f-word. It's pretty extreme. Vitriolic would be an appropriate term.

Comment: @JavaLatte The f-word? Is it a response to the c-words ['How a Bunch of C-Words Got Into the Oxford English Dictionary'?](http://time.com/24990/how-a-bunch-of-c-words-got-into-the-oxford-english-dictionary/)?

Comment: @Student The f-word and the c-word are two different things figuratively and literally

Comment: We really shouldn't use euphemisms that learners may not understand. If you're not willing to type out fuck or cunt, or whatever other vulgar word you're going to refer to as the X-word, you really should rephrase so you don't need to. @JavaLatte

Comment: This link gives a useful summary of perceived offensiveness: http://www.theguardian.com/media/broadcast/table/0,7493,409833,00.html though bastard isn't rated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be surprising to read or hear a reporter calling someone a "contemptuous bastard" in a regular news article or news story. These stories, in the Western press at least, are usually objective accounts of events or developments. (Of course, newspapers have their own view on things, so they aren't completely objective.) Thus even a news story on, say,  the alleged or convicted   terrorist responsible for the attacks in Paris would not be call "contemptuous bastard", no matter the personal opinion of the reporter. A news story might quote a person who says that about someone, whether the someone deserves it or not.

However, in an editorial or opinion piece about some person, in your case Iain Duncan-Smith, the writer is freer to use subjective terms that express the writer's own opinion of a situation or person. This can include such strong terms as the one you ask about. Whether it is considered "rude" or not probably depends on the reader's view of the topic or subject of the story.

This use of language, in fact, is one way to determine what type of article you are reading.